# Wrong urls generated, wordpress theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, url, plugins

I have problem after using all-in-one wp-migrate. I export page to other domain and then I have problem with include css and js files in personalization page. This files have wrong url, becouse there are "/wp-content/plugins":

For example(there are about 50 links like that, with css and js files):

There is:

```
/wp-content/plugins/wp-content/themes/classiadspro/includes/framework/ReduxCore/assets/css/redux-admin.css
```

Should be:

```
/wp-content/themes/classiadspro/includes/framework/ReduxCore/assets/css/redux-admin.css
```

I can't find where are generate this links. I think it's something wrong with some function file, but I can't find it. Please help where I can change that.

Answer (score 0):

You should regenerate permalinks after migration using *All-in-One WP Migration*. On the left side menu, select **Settings > Permalinks**, then click **Save Changes**. It’s unnecessary to edit any of the default permalink structure information. Repeat saving once again (twice at all) and now it should be ok.

Comment: it doesn't help. Pages don't includes files in personalization page and in themes options in WP-Admin.